# Some "http://" links in the election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election, ssl

In the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9), a few of the links for the badges and MSE sites are still `http://`, these links can be updated to `https://`

Screenshot for reference:

[image: http:// links]

Comment: @CodyGray It's freehand only, my hand writing is really good.